# ckeditor4 autocomplete plugin add behavior on commmit

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using ckeditor4 and the autocomplete plugin. I am looking to perform some additional actions on autocomplete select ( When the 'enter' or 'tab' keys are pressed ).

I see in the autocomplete [source code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/blob/major/plugins/autocomplete/plugin.js) there is the `commit: function( itemId )`. Does anyone know of or have a suggestion on a reasonable way to either override this function or have some additional code execute when this function is called?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by overriding the plugins function in my ckeditor config.js file:

```js
CKEDITOR.plugins.autocomplete.prototype.commit = function( itemId ) { ... }
```